# sql joining as alias does not working

Tags: sql, database, join, alias

i am new to sql joins.. i have project that is 5 year old . Now i have to deploy it some new server .so deploy it to other server there i am facing some sql problem. here is the qyery .

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.*,DATE_FORMAT(d.downloads_updated, '%c/%d/%Y') AS updated,DATE_FORMAT(d.downloads_created, '%c/%d/%Y') AS created, s2.strings_english as title, s2.strings_english as description 
FROM strings s, downloads d,
 products_has_downloads pd 
inner JOIN strings s2 ON d.downloads_description = s.strings_id WHERE d.downloads_id = pd.downloads_id AND s.strings_id = d.downloads_title AND d.downloads_status = 'Live' AND d.downloads_level = 'Public'
 ORDER BY d.downloads_updated DESC LIMIT 5
```

i am getting this error

```
1054 - Unknown column 'd.downloads_description' in 'on clause'
```

i have not written this sql query.it is working fine on old server .

I am new to join and database .please can any one help me .

Comment: Does the `downloads` table contain a `downloads_description` field? You should be able to check that yourself very easily.

Comment: Is there any"d.downloads_description" column?

Comment: yes in `downloads` table there is "d.downloads_description" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing both implicit and explicit join syntax which will not work.

You have the following implicit syntax where the tables are joined by commas:

```
FROM strings s, downloads d, products_has_downloads pd
```

The `JOIN` syntax has a higher precedence to the comma syntax so the alias for `downloads` is not available in the `ON` clause.

Try using all of the same syntax. I changed your query to use only explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.*,
  DATE_FORMAT(d.downloads_updated, '%c/%d/%Y') AS updated,
  DATE_FORMAT(d.downloads_created, '%c/%d/%Y') AS created, 
s2.strings_english as title, 
s2.strings_english as description 
FROM strings s
INNER JOIN downloads d
  ON d.downloads_description = s.strings_id
INNER JOIN products_has_downloads pd 
  on d.downloads_id = pd.downloads_id
inner JOIN strings s2 
  on s2.strings_id = d.downloads_title
WHERE d.downloads_status = 'Live' 
  AND d.downloads_level = 'Public'
ORDER BY d.downloads_updated DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: yes your solution is working good.. but i have a question why this is working fine on my old server . my question query is fetching result at my old server

Comment: @SheikhJames depending on your system, some [older systems would allow it](http://chase-seibert.github.com/blog/2009/04/17/mixing-and-matching-implicit-and-explicit-joins.html) but they should not. I believe most newer systems will prevent this type of mixing.